# Listbox.Items.Clear() crashes on SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox

```
private void lbcreatedRequests_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

}

//Display Edit Page
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   lbcreatedRequests.Items.Clear(); //crash here 
   _loggedIn = Home._loggedIn;
    if (_loggedIn == true)
    {
       wcf.retrievecreatedrequestListAsync(Home.myID);
    }
}
```

Trying to clear the `Listbox`, before it load the new one again

Error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at SGTaxiPool.Views.ShareCab.lbcreatedRequests_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectionChanged>(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InvokeSelectionChanged(List`1 unselectedItems, List`1 selectedItems)
>     at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
>     at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>     at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object >sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.NotifyCollectionChanged>(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.ClearImpl()
>     at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.Clear()
>     at SGTaxiPool.Views.ShareCab.btnEdit_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
>     at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
>     at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
>     at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName

Comment: How can this possibly have 3 upvotes? There is no info at all

Comment: BrokenGlass' answer was correct.  Too bad he deleted it.  He linked to this: http://forums.silverlight.net/p/17967/73247.aspx

Comment: Hopefully @BrokenGlass can add the answer again. Just tried it and he was correct. The exception given is `InvalidOperationException` with the message `Cannot change ItemCollection during a OnItemsChanged event.`

Comment: Well guess I'm undeleting then, who knew - I wasn't sure this still applies on the full release, that thread was about Beta 2

Comment: @BrokenGlass there was some useful info on how to reproduce in that post. If you add items using XAML and then clear, there is no problem. But if you add items using code and then clear, the exception occurs

Comment: @Tedd Don't change the entire question. This is **not** the same question as before

Comment: http://forums.silverlight.net/p/17967/73247.aspx <-- 30mins ago tried it, but doesn't work

Comment: @Tedd: I'd like to re-inforce Oskar's comment.  You should absolutely keep the original question as was so that A) any existing answers still makes sense and B) anyone else having the same __original__ problem as you can see that your question matches their problem and then find an answer.  Without that Stackoverflow loses its reason to exist.  If you have a subsquent problem create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/17967/73247.aspx) suggests a workaround for this problem is to do this on the Dispatcher thread:

```
private void lbcreatedRequests_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { lbcreatedRequests.Items.Clear(); });
}
```